# Remove duplicates in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list containing the strings

```
a=['boy', 'girl', 'man', 'boy']
```

Now I want a new list that doesn't have repeated elements

```
b = ['boy', 'girl', 'man']
```

How do I do that in Python?

Comment: Create a dictionary, using the List items as keys. This will automatically remove any duplicates because dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. like list(dict.fromkeys(a)) where a = ['boy', 'girl', 'man', 'boy']

Answer (score 1):

from [DOC](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/) of `set`:

|Sets are mutable unordered collections of unique elements.

use `set` like below:

```
a=['boy', 'girl', 'man', 'boy']

list(set(a))
```

output:

```
['man', 'boy', 'girl']
```

by thanks of @jonrsharpe for maintaining of list's order you can try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a=['boy', 'girl', 'man', 'boy']
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a))
```

output:

```
['boy', 'girl', 'man']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
  
a=['boy', 'girl', 'man', 'boy']
b = ['boy', 'girl', 'man']

print("Union of two arrays :", np.union1d(a, b))
```